# UIWebView doesn't detect phone number links

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, tel

I'm building an app with a UIWebView in it.

The webView should load html that includes tel: links:

```
<a href="tel:123456789">call me</a>
```

The webView doesn't make the "call me" link to be clickable.

I tried

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber
```

But doesn't work.

I looked in all the stackOverflow Q&A's and found no answer specific to this problem.

Thanks for your help,
Nur

Comment: i had made a same dummy code as u had described it is working here                                                          NSString *str = @" <a href=\"tel:123456789\">call me</a>";
webview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;

    [webview loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
<a href="tel:123456789"> call me </a>
```

with

```
<a href="tel://123456789">call me</a>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: It's works for me. If you want can use the delegate methods as under

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;    
    
    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me

Add the web view

```
web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:WEBVIEW_FRAME];
web.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink | UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"new" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]];
web.delegate  =self;
[self.view addSubview:web];
```

and the delegate method

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                            navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
     if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"])
     {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
     }
}
```

and my html file

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <h1>HTML PAGE</h1>
  </head>
  <a href="tel:123456789"> call me </a>
  </html>
```