# How to get detected number in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, phone-number, tel

is there a possibility to get number detected in `UIWebView`.

When I click a number inside UIWebView on my iPad I get popover with following choices:

Send Message, Add to Contacts, Copy.

How can I remove that popover and get detected number?

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,1024,768)];
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"somepage"]; 
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

`UIWebView` detects phone numbers and when I click on number, system shows me popover.

Interesting thing is that none of the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods is called when I tap on the number.

I only need to get detected number.

Comment: We'd really need to see your existing code before we could give you a good answer but your first port of call would probably be the method that handles the click.

Answer (score 1):

Stop detecting numbers and have them as links instead. So when you press the link (Number) it will take you into the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method.

The code below should help I have commented to detail what each line does if you need anything else just ask.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    static NSString *urlPrefix = @"tel://";
    NSString *url = [[request url] absoluteString]; // Notice that we are getting the obsoluteString of the url 
    if([url hasPrefix:urlPrefix]) { // We then check that the url has a prefix of our urlPrefix otherwise why bother doing anything at all.
       if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenUrl:url]) { // This is to check that we can actually open a url as iPads can't make phone calls.
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:url]; // And if everything is successful we are good to make the phone call.
           return NO; // We don't want the UIWebView to go navigating somewhere crazy so tell it to stop navigating away.
       } else {
           return NO; // If it does contain the prefix but we can't open the url we don't want to navigate away so return NO.
       }
    }

    return YES; // If all else fails it most be a standard request so return YES.
}
```

The code will work on a link like:

```
<p>Call us on:<a href="tel://12345678900">12345678900</a></p>
```

**UPDATE**

I have just realized that you aren't setting your `webView`s delegate. So in your .h file make sure you have:

```
@interface MyClassName : MySuperClass <UIWebViewDelegate> // Obviously 'MyClassName' and MySuperClass' you need to replace with your classes.
```

then after `UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,1024,768)];` you need to do `[webView setDelegate:self];` this will set it up so it should use the delegate methods.

If you have any more issues just leave a comment.

Comment: App never enters in this delegate method when url starts with "tel:". Instead only shows popover and do not enter in delegate method.

Comment: @user3074207 I think that could be because you are still detecting telephone numbers (`UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber`) stop detecting them so it turns it into a normal link. I also just noticed that you haven't set your `webViews` delegate doing `[webView setDelegate:self];` after you initialize the webview. Check my UPDATE

Comment: As Nikola Nikolic says, the delegate methods are not called on the iPad. On the iPhone everything works perfectly. But on the iPad, even with the delegate set (and the detection off - although this is irrelevant if you actually have a tel: link - like my case), the shouldStartLoadWithRequest: method is bypassed for the tel: links. The popover appears instead. Any ideas?

Comment: the usual phone prefix is no longer `"tel://"`, you should use `"tel:"` instead

Answer (score -1):

Use following delegate method to detect phone number :

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                            navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
     if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"])
     {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
     }
}
```

Here is the reference thread : [UIWebView doesn't detect phone number links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430058/uiwebview-doesnt-detect-phone-number-links)